# Qt QWebView loading error linking some SSL libraries?

Tags: qt, plugins, ssl, qwebview

So i'm creating a mini browser with Qt and using `QWebView`. It loads some pages okay, but some of them have problems with SSL because i'm getting this errors:

```
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
```

I had previous issues with libraries and `QTPlugins`, and I haven't had any success in liking static plugins (more specifically image formats). I have no ideea how to solve these issues, as i am fairly new to QT framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem appears to be present only on Linux platforms, these plugins are not included somehow when you install `QtCreator`.

I have found no solution or documentation on this whatsoever.

However the problem does not appear on Windows, and QWebView works just fine for all functionalities.